# Control the maximum characters per line

Tags: gmail

Gmail displays all the emails I sent in a maximum number of characters per line. This limit is half of that for display of others' emails sent to me.

Can I control the limit number:

- in general
- for an individual email
- for a line in an email (because for a line of code, it is better not to break it however long it may be)?

Comment: Gmail doesn't force wrapping anywhere. Could it be your browser or perhaps a browser extension that modifies how textareas work? Can you provide a screen shot of what you're seeing?

Comment: If you turn on HTML formatting gmail doesn't add line breaks.